# Spring Cloud Contract not executing @Before

Tags: java, spring, api, testing

I am writing tests using Spring Cloud Contract.
In my configuration I am using for test an in memory DB that is created and destroyed at each test run.
In order to test successfully I need to put some data in the DB but it seems like the classic @Before annotation used in jUnit does not work (the code in it is never executed).

```
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;


@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BaseTestClass {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseTestClass.class);

    @Autowired
    EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        // This code never runs
        LOGGER.info("Init started");
        MyEntity entity1 = new MyEntity();
        entityRepository.save(entity1);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(context);
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see an import for `@Before`. What is it?

Comment: I added it now, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that works.

I was adding the @TestInstance decorator incorrectly, here's my working solution:

```
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;


@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class BaseTestClass {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseTestClass.class);

    @Autowired
    EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @BeforeAll
    public void init() {
        LOGGER.info("Init started");
        MyEntity entity1 = new MyEntity();
        entityRepository.save(entity1);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(context);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`@Before` belongs to JUnit4 and earlier while `@BeforeEach` belongs to JUnit5 as a replacement and clarification of `@Before`. If you are running with JUnit5, perhaps put all your initialization logic in `@BeforeEach` (or if it's a one-time init, in `@BeforeAll`)

Comment: I also tried @BeforeEach but it forces me to use static (that will not work because I need repository to save data into DB) or to use something like  @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS) and then I get "@TestInstance not applicable to method") and it won't compile.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me again in the right direction :)